# Remove blinking effet bootstrap dropdown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

While modifying Bootstrap vanilla's css, I found a weird blinking effect when you click on a dropdown then click outside of it (in the body for example) :

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
  .navbar-default {
    background-color: #222;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-brand,
  .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #FFF;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:focus,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open {
    background-color: #444;
    color: #FFF;
  }
  @media (min-width: 3000px) and (max-width: 3000px) {
    .collapse {
      display: none !important;
    }
  }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

**To make the snippet actually displays the error, you need to see it within a full page.**

---

I also made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ey60rrs2/) to make things clearer, and less difficult to explain.

Do you have any idea about which css selector should I use to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to style your dropdown link instead of the dropdown itself by adding this in your css :

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a {
    background-color:#222; 
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Including more tags and classes will hold a [higher priority](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) over a style on the same element without the extra classes.
For instance :  just adding `body` before a class can make the class more specific.

---

I've [updatded your JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98o4kakg/12/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

The element you need is the a.dropdown-toggle. I don't know how much specific is bootstrap when styling it, or even if it uses inline-style, but if you use !important you can see that the blinking stops.

```
.dropdown-toggle {
     background-color: transparent !important;   
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98o4kakg/5/)

Update: 
Bootstrap uses: .nav .open>a, .nav .open>a:focus, .nav .open>a:hover

Answer (score 0):

Check out with the below link and let me know if its working fine now.

https://jsfiddle.net/98o4kakg/3/

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open {
    background-color: #444;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: That works on yours, but not on mine, indeed you can see that your dropdown has a light background when you focus it, instead of mine which is dark, that's why we can't see the blink in yours

Comment: The blink your getting is the same light color background I am getting in mine when you click on the dropdown. I have just removed  a:focus, form your css line number 13.

Comment: Yeah I knew that, and this is why I now need to know from which selector this background blink is created in order to change color when the user focuses out of the dropdown

Comment: You can have a look at it now its working fine. Please check the link.    https://jsfiddle.net/98o4kakg/6/